# Can I replace a 2007 VW Rabbit key's transponder chip?

Tags: vw, key, ignition-key, fob

My key fob was in really bad shape and I was replacing the outer shell. All was going well and working, but as I tried to get the glass transponder chip out of the old key, it shattered. Is there a way to order a pre-programed one (I have an RFID reader), or are they all coded the same? I still have a working FOB so I should be able to read the code.

Answer (score -1):

Every rfid chip is coded differently, never configured as duplicates. Used as animal identification (inserted under the skin), Mobil Speed Pass instead of credit card for pumping gas, vehicle antitheft and in US passports. Rfid chipped ignition keys are programmed to the vehicle and do not come preprogrammed. If you have your owner's manual, it may have instructions for programming at home after a new key is cut or require VW to program it to your car. There may a service manual describing dealer or at home programming the car to replacement rfid ignition keys. Your car electronics is part of programming since the rfid chip is learned and memorized in one of the electronic modules in the car.

Answer (score -1):

When I broke a key, the main agent offered to replace it for about 200 GBP with a down-payment, and I presumed they would program the new key from their records.

However only the key blade had broken, and the local key/heel/photo store supplied a pattern one for a fraction of the cost. They have a device to copy the code.

If the broken electronics prevent that happening, copy the spare, and if you don't have *that* go to the franchised dealer.